# Laravel - Fresh VueJS and Inertia app giving error: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have just done a fresh install of inertia on an app with vuejs (v2) and am getting this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead.
```

But I don't see why it's trying to mount on those elements? As far as I can tell I've followed the inertia installation guide....

web.php

```
Route::get('test', function(){return \Inertia\Inertia::render('master');});
```

app-ihf.js

```
import { App, plugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import Vue from 'vue'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress'

Vue.use(plugin)

const el = document.getElementById('app')

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App, {
        props: {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(el.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: name => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
        },
    }),
}).$mount(el)

InertiaProgress.init()
```

master.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app-ihf.css">
    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app-ihf.js') }}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @inertia
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone see what's going wrong here? This is the html when you visit that route

```
<html><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app-ihf.css?id=fc17ae1fae0b57440a59">
    <script src="/js/app-ihf.js?id=fa7eba2a2c660c498a3e"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app" data-page="{&quot;component&quot;:&quot;master&quot;,&quot;props&quot;:{&quot;errors&quot;:{}},&quot;url&quot;:&quot;\/test&quot;,&quot;version&quot;:&quot;3993c0d73e25e92aa0e15607a6c438ef&quot;}"></div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you also share your Inertia middleware config?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and it's because I didn't put `defer` into the script tag so the JavaScript in app.js was running before the `id="app"` element existed on the page.

So in your case you need:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app-ihf.js') }}" defer></script>
```